# Apache beam StateSpec in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-beam

I am using StateSpec in beam and running that with spark runner

I am getting following error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Found StateId annotations on com.walmart.rum.StreamingApp$3, but DoFn cannot yet be used with state in the SparkRunner.
>       at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.TranslationUtils.rejectStateAndTimers(TranslationUtils.java:269)

So does this means we StateSpec is not entirely supported or some version it is supported ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

States and Timers are **supported only** in Batch mode and **not supported** in Streaming mode for Spark runner. It seems that you have streaming application and that is why it's failing.

Comment: Is there any way to share state b/w DoFns 
as StateSpec is not supported

Comment: Do you mean batch or streaming mode? In streaming mode (when you use unbounded input source), Spark runner check every DoFn and if it contains states annotations then it will fail.