# Apache Beam UnsupportedOperationException on upgrade from 2.29.0 to 2.32.0

Tags: apache-beam

I have a pipeline that has been working for a year fine on version 2.29.0. However this week we can't build anymore due to this [dependency](https://maven.repository.redhat.com/earlyaccess/all/com/google/guava/guava/31.1.0.redhat-00001/) that has been removed from Redhat Maven repo. I upgraded our pipeline to Beam version 2.32.0. Our pipeline uses the SparkRunner and the version of Spark is: 3.2.0. However the new Beam version is throwing an exception.  Below is the error I receive plus the stack trace. Any body has any idea what I need to configure/change to get it working again?

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Found StateId annotations on org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.GroupIntoBatches$GroupIntoBatchesDoFn, but DoFn cannot yet be used with state in the SparkRunner.
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.TranslationUtils.rejectStateAndTimers(TranslationUtils.java:271)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.StreamingTransformTranslator$9.evaluate(StreamingTransformTranslator.java:418)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.StreamingTransformTranslator$9.evaluate(StreamingTransformTranslator.java:409)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$Evaluator.doVisitTransform(SparkRunner.java:449)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner$Evaluator.visitPrimitiveTransform(SparkRunner.java:438)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:593)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:585)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:240)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:214)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:469)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.SparkRunnerStreamingContextFactory.call(SparkRunnerStreamingContextFactory.java:88)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.translation.streaming.SparkRunnerStreamingContextFactory.call(SparkRunnerStreamingContextFactory.java:46)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext$.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(JavaStreamingContext.scala:628)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext$.getOrCreate(StreamingContext.scala:841)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext$.getOrCreate(JavaStreamingContext.scala:627)
at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.getOrCreate(JavaStreamingContext.scala)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:180)
at org.apache.beam.runners.spark.SparkRunner.run(SparkRunner.java:96)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:323)
at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:309)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Beam Capability Matrix](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/capability-matrix/) and this answer [Apache beam StateSpec in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58034153/apache-beam-statespec-in-spark), stateful processing is not supported in streaming pipelines with SparkRunner.